# Using levenshtein to match target string + extra text

Tags: php, levenshtein-distance

I'm working on a website conversion project, and I need to match inexact strings. I'm looking at using leveshtein, but I don't know what parameters I should set for my task.

Say I have a target string `elephant`. The match I would want to pull is `elephant mouse`, for example

```
<?

$target = "elephant";

$data = array(
  'elephant mouse',
  'rhinoceros',
  'alligator',
  'hippopotamus',
  'rat',
);

foreach ( $data as $datum ) {
  echo "$target >> $datum == " .  levenshtein($target, $datum) . "\n";
}
```

And I get the result

```
elephant >> elephant mouse == 6
elephant >> rhinoceros == 10
elephant >> alligator == 7
elephant >> hippopotamus == 10
elephant >> rat == 7
```

So while `rhino` and `hippo` are at 10, in my actual data set, I couldn't really tell the difference between `elephant mouse`, `rat` and `alligator`, which are neck-and-neck at 6 and 7. This is bogus data, but in my data set, words that are closer in length only get a much lower score than words that are `target + extra`.

How should I configure the options of `levenshtein()`? I can set new integer values for the cost of insertion, replacement, and deletion. What weighting will give me what I want?

(If you can think of a better title please edit my post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weighting `levenshtein($target, $datum, 1, 10, 10)` gives me

```
elephant >> elephant mouse == 6
elephant >> rhinoceros == 65
elephant >> alligator == 52
elephant >> hippopotamus == 64
elephant >> rat == 60
```

Which works very well :) Insertion is a low cost, while both replacement and deletion are high. This means that `target + extra` has a low score, where strings of equal or shorter length, but different characters, have a high cost.

Comment: Unfortunately, this also gives a low score to strings that contain the correct characters, but with many other characters inbetween, e.g. "qwErtyLasdEdgfhdPasdxcHdfjAlkjNlkhTkjh". There is no way to get the Levenshtein algorithm to prioritize letters that occur within the same word over letters in different words, as the algorithm has no concept of a "word".

Comment: At least in the dataset I'm dealing with, this isn't a problem. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try to match individual words with `levenshtein()` rather than entire phrases, since you apparently want to consider a phrase a good match if it contains something that resembles the word being searched for. In other words, split each string in `$datum` into individual words, run `levenshtein($target, $word)` for each word, and pick the lowest number. (If `$target` also can consist of multiple words, you need to split that one too.)

I strongly doubt that you can achieve the desired effect by tweaking the insertion/deletion/replacement costs, because the Levenshtein doesn't consider individual words, only the string as a whole. You could try to make insertion very cheap, but that would also give a good score to e.g. "qwErtyLasdEdgfhdPasdxcHdfjAlkjNlkhTkjh" since it contains all the right letters.